# How to update apk through code

Tags: android

My application is already installed in the devise and i will get notification that you want to update, at one click i want my application get updated programmatically. Is there anyway to do...

Comment: I think there are way you have to uninstall app then install again.

Comment: That is the job of market app. Why are you circumventing it?

Comment: Thanks for your responses, @Newts, can you suggest some ways to do that without user help

Comment: @AdityaKumarPandey, my app will not be in market, just i will give notification to user to update. After clicking OK button it has to get updated.

Answer (score 0):

Third party developers are not able to install .apk files directly without user intervention.

But you can send request to `PackageManager` to handle installation of new .apk file. This will show "install the app" dialog to user, and if she accepts the installation, your update will go through.

An example of the described scenario: [Android: install .apk programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

The only way i'm seeing of doing that, and its NOT a good policy it to have the initial code swapping a specific directory for classes, and if it founds one, load it by reflection on the fly and "replacing" the classe contained in the APK

I don't think this will have a good performance... and should not i repeat NOT be a policy for update.